# Changing Bootstrap module with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I a database with employee names and when you search for a employee names a list shows up and in them i have a Notes table using bootstrap "alert alert-info" banner for notes but i want it to do this: If the Table called notes on the database says WARNING: in it change the banner to "alert alert-danger" any help?

Here is my code to the Search.php

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("***", "***", "**") or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a7172755_search")or die("Could not find Database");
//Collect
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['FirstName'])) { //Search box
    $searchq = $_POST['FirstName']; //NOT VALID
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR LastName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR DateofBirth LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Address LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Occupation LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Warrents LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Record LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Email LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Phone LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Mobile LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Notes LIKE '%$searchq%' OR Photo LIKE '%$searchq%' OR OnlineName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR FaceBookName LIKE '%$searchq%' OR WarningNotes LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search!"); //Gets the Table
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = '<h3 class="alert alert-warning" style="text-align:center;">No one under that name could be found!</h3>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $fname = $row['FirstName'];
            $lname = $row['LastName'];
            $dob = $row['DateofBirth'];
            $address = $row['Address'];
            $occupation = $row['Occupation'];
            $warrents = $row['Warrents'];
            $record = $row['Record'];
            $email = $row['Email'];
            $phone = $row['Phone'];
            $mobile = $row['Mobile'];
            $notes = $row['Notes'];
            $photo = $row['Photo'];
            $onlinename = $row['OnlineName'];
            $facebookname = $row['FaceBookName'];
            //$id = $row['ID']; Not Needed


            $output .= '<img src ="Photo/'.$photo.'.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><div style="margin-left: 300px;"><p>First Name: '.$fname.'<br>Last Name: '.$lname. '<br>Date of Birth: '.$dob.'<br>Address: '.$address.'<br>Occupation: '.$occupation.'<br>Warrents '.$warrents.'<br>Criminal Record: '.$record.'<br>Email Adress: '.$email.'<br>Phone: '.$phone.'<br>Mobile: '.$mobile.'<br>Online Name: '.$OnlineName.'<br>FaceBook Name/URL: '.$FaceBookName.'<div class="alert alert-info">Notes: '.$notes.'</div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More >></button></p></div><hr>';
        }
    }
    }

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/et-lineicon.css" />
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="form-signin-header" style="margin-left: 500px;" >Persons Search</h2>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <?php print("$output");?>
        </div>

                    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: You may want to take the [tour]. After that, you might want to think about using punctuation. After all, you want people to help you. That is unlikely to happen when you don't show any effort yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the while loop too:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fname = $row['FirstName'];
        $lname = $row['LastName'];
        $dob = $row['DateofBirth'];
        $address = $row['Address'];
        $occupation = $row['Occupation'];
        $warrents = $row['Warrents'];
        $record = $row['Record'];
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $phone = $row['Phone'];
        $mobile = $row['Mobile'];
        $notes = $row['Notes'];
        $photo = $row['Photo'];
        $onlinename = $row['OnlineName'];
        $facebookname = $row['FaceBookName'];
        //$id = $row['ID']; Not Needed

        // Check the notes text and set the label for the div
        if($notes == "WARNING") { 
             $label = "danger";
        } else {
             $label = "info";
        }

        $output .= '<img src ="Photo/'.$photo.'.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><div style="margin-left: 300px;"><p>First Name: '.$fname.'<br>Last Name: '.$lname. '<br>Date of Birth: '.$dob.'<br>Address: '.$address.'<br>Occupation: '.$occupation.'<br>Warrents '.$warrents.'<br>Criminal Record: '.$record.'<br>Email Adress: '.$email.'<br>Phone: '.$phone.'<br>Mobile: '.$mobile.'<br>Online Name: '.$OnlineName.'<br>FaceBook Name/URL: '.$FaceBookName.'<div class="alert alert-'.$label.'">Notes: '.$notes.'</div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">More >></button></p></div><hr>';
    }
```

Comment: it worked great but 1 problem, say if i type the label as WARNING it turn red but if i change the value to WARNING - MESSAGE it turns blue again any ideas? Cause each time i want it to read the WARNING only and ignore the rest of the characters if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know what your table is called and the field.

For example:

```
<?php

$fetch_alert = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT `note_label`, `alert_text` FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = '1'")); 

if($fetch_alert->note_label == "WARNING") { 
    echo"<div class=alert alert-danger"">".$fetch_alert->alert_text."</div>"; 
} else {
    echo"<div class=alert alert-info"">".$fetch_alert->alert_text."</div>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: I added my code to my post please take a look whenever you can.